# Javascript Audio Visualization

Tags: javascript

I'm making a small recording feature using the user/browser microphone. When the microphone is getting sound an audio visualization is shown (like an equalizer). So fare so good.

But i really want to change the way the visualization looks to something like the image below. But i have never worked with this area before and don't know how to go about it.

I imagine something like this:
https://images.app.goo.gl/pfKgnGnQz3MJVkbW6
[image]

**I have two questions:**

1. Is it possible to get a result like the attached?
2. How do you get started on something like that? (or has anyone done something like this that can share examples?)

My current code for the equlizer visualization

```
audioContext = new AudioContext();
gumStream = stream;
input = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
rec = new Recorder(input,{numChannels:1})
rec.record()

inputPoint = audioContext.createGain();
audioInput = input;
audioInput.connect(inputPoint);

analyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
analyserNode.fftSize = 1024;
inputPoint.connect( analyserNode );
updateAnalysers();

function updateAnalysers(time) {
if (!analyserContext) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("analyser");
    canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    analyserContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

{
    var SPACING = 5;
    var BAR_WIDTH = 5;
    var numBars = Math.round(canvasWidth / SPACING);
    var freqByteData = new Uint8Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);

    analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(freqByteData); 

    analyserContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    analyserContext.fillStyle = '#D5E9EB';
    analyserContext.lineCap = 'round';
    var multiplier = analyserNode.frequencyBinCount / numBars;

    // Draw rectangle for each frequency bin.
    for (var i = 0; i < numBars; ++i) {
        var magnitude = 0;
        var offset = Math.floor( i * multiplier );
        for (var j = 0; j< multiplier; j++)
            magnitude += freqByteData[offset + j];
        magnitude = magnitude / multiplier;
        var magnitude2 = freqByteData[i * multiplier];
        analyserContext.fillRect(i * SPACING, canvasHeight, BAR_WIDTH, -magnitude);
    }
}

rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers );
}
```

Comment: Answers:1 - yes, 2 - there's some useful code included in the question. This question needs to focus on some specific issue.

Comment: "Something more modern"? That's vague.

Comment: Good point. Was hoping the image would illustrate what i had in mind. And if it was broken, i have tried to insert it again and also a link.

Comment: Your example image looks like it has two overlapping waveforms? How are you expecting that to work in practice?

Comment: I was thinking that different segments of the pitch could be responsible for it's own layer. So bass-level has a layer, same for middle and treble. If something like that is possible?

Comment: Just found this, which is the drawing that i want. https://www.cssscript.com/siri-audio-waveform/ - Don't know if it connects to a microphone input. It might just be a simulation.

Comment: Found a solution with codepen and it worked like a charm https://codepen.io/fgnass/pen/LWeKNq (The specific ex. would only work in FF, needs some tweeking to make it work in other browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Ans 1 :

Your image is broken so can't answer but as far as I know, you can visualize any waveform using audio data

How do you get started on something like that? (or has anyone done something like this that can share examples?)

Ans 2:

So I did use the customized waveform. I am sharing my code

```js
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import AudioVisualiser from "./AudioVisualiser";

    class AudioAnalyser extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { audioData: new Uint8Array(0) };
        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.audioContext = new (window.AudioContext ||
          window.webkitAudioContext)();
        this.analyser = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();
        this.dataArray = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        this.source = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.props.audio);
        this.source.connect(this.analyser);
        this.rafId = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
      }

      tick() {
        this.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(this.dataArray);
        this.setState({ audioData: this.dataArray });
        this.rafId = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafId);
        // this.analyser.disconnect();
        // this.source.disconnect();
      }

      render() {
        return <AudioVisualiser audioData={this.state.audioData} />;
      }
    }

    export default AudioAnalyser;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AudioVisualiser extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.canvas = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    const { audioData } = this.props;
    const canvas = this.canvas.current;
    const height = canvas.height;
    const width = canvas.width;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let x = 0;
    const sliceWidth = (width * 1.0) / audioData.length;

    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, height / 2);
    for (const item of audioData) {
      const y = (item / 255.0) * height;
      context.lineTo(x, y);
      x += sliceWidth;
    }
    context.lineTo(x, height / 2);
    context.stroke();
  }

  render() {
    return <canvas width="300" height="300" ref={this.canvas} />;
  }
}

export default AudioVisualiser;
```

Comment: Please don't use snippets for code that doesn't run. Use normal code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have updated the picture and also inserted a link. Hopefully it works this time.